# Which Latin verb was closer to the current meaning of English "solve"?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, medieval-latin, late-latin, spanish

Nowadays the English verb *solve* [means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solve):

> Find an answer to, explanation for, or means of effectively dealing with (a problem or mystery).

The [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/solve#etymonline_v_23868) of the word indicates that it comes:

> from Latin *solvere* "to loosen, dissolve; untie, release, detach; depart; unlock; scatter; dismiss; accomplish, fulfill; explain; remove".

Nonetheless, the verb used in Spanish with the same meaning is *[resolver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC)* (my translation of the definition):

> Solve a problem, a doubt, a difficulty or something that involves them.

This verb comes from Latin *[resolvĕre](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=resolvo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, from *re-* and *[solvĕre](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=solvo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*. So in Latin there also existed the verb *resolvĕre*. Both verbs appear in the Lewis & Short dictionary, but their meanings appear to be somewhat different from (or maybe broader than) the current ones for both English and Spanish. So both *solve* and *resolver* have the same meaning today but come from different verbs *solvo* and *resolvo*. Question: Which one of them was most used in Latin for the same context as today's verbs? Or maybe both were used but in different periods?

---

<sub>Note: in Spanish there also existed a verb *[solver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YJmavLR)* with the same meaning as *solve* and *resolver*, but was already deprecated in the 18th century.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is a "famous" phrase attributed to St. Augustine: "*[solvitur ambulando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvitur_ambulando)*", meaning "it [the problem] is solved by walking". I have failed to track down such phrase in Augustine's texts (which can be found [here](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/index.htm)). However, a search for words related to *solvere* in Augustine's texts yields several hits that, as far as I can tell, imply the meaning of the English "to solve". For instance, [here](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/questioni_ettateuco/quest_ettateuco_1_libro.htm) you get:

> Solvitur ergo quaestio per recapitulationem, quae indissolubilis remaneret, ...
>
> Recapitulatio itaque ista, si advertatur in Scripturis, multas quaestiones solvit, ...
>
> Sic itaque solvitur ista quaestio.

Conversely, searching words related to the verb *resolvere* do not seem to give the English meaning. For instance, [here](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/lettere/lettera_141_testo.htm) you get:

> At vero flante austro, glacies resolvitur, et torrentes fluunt, ...

The above is merely based on search for one author. Not sure how representative of the corpus us though.

Comment: Quite interesting. I have just seen that the verb "resolver" in Spanish in the 15th century was close to "dissolve" or "decompose", as in the example "gracies resolvitur": "Cada cosa se resuelve en aquello de que fue compuesta" (1428).